# Prove that if a|b, c|d, then ac|bd

Tags: divisibility

I'm trying to prove it, but I can't find how.

If `a divides b`, and `c divides d`, then `a*c divides b*d`

Comment: We can also formulate the claim in terms of mods. Specifically if $b \equiv 0 \pmod a $ and $d \equiv 0 \pmod c $ then $ bd \equiv 0 \pmod {ac} $

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:** $a\mid b$ means that there exists an integer $k$ such that $b = ka$.

---

You seem to have written the essential step as a comment.  Here's how it would fit into a complete proof:

> Suppose that $a\mid b$ and $c \mid d$. It follows that we have $b = k_1 a$ and $d = k_2 c$ for integers $k_1, k_2$.  It follows that
> $$
> bd = (k_1a)(k_2c) = (k_1k_2)(ac)
> $$
> Let $k$ be equal to the integer $k_1 k_2$. We see that $(bd) = k(ac)$. Thus, $bd$ is divisible by $ac$.

Comment: I've reached `k1* a * k2 * c = k * a * c` but then I don't know how to procede, because it would be `k1 * k2 = k`

Comment: See my latest edit

Comment: Thanks that was what I was needing. I've tried for a time, it's not that easy for me.

Answer (score 0):

It goes directly from the definition of divisibility.
If $a|b$ then exists $k$ such that $b=ka$.
If $c|d$ then exists $l$ such that $d=lc$.
Hence $bd=klac$.